# My repository can't initialize automatically while using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to add spring data jpa to my spring-mvc web project after exploring a couple of tutorials. But I found my repository can't initialize automatically, I got NullPointerException in my service class. Please see my following sample code:

My repository:

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends JpaRepository<PSubject, String>{
public Page<PSubject> findByType(String title, Pageable pageable);
public Page<PSubject> findByType(String title);
public Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress, Pageable pageable);
public Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress);
public Page<PSubject> findByUri(String uri);
```

}

My controller：

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/subject")  
public class VPSubjectController
{
....
@RequestMapping("/{id}.htm")
    public ModelAndView detail(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("subject/detail");
        PSubject subject = subjectService.get(id);
....
}
}
```

My Service：

```
@Service("subjectService")
public class SubjectServiceImpl extends VPService implements SubjectService
{

    @Autowired
    private SubjectRepository subjectRepository;
......
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
    public PSubject get(String subject) {
        PSubject subObj = subjectRepository.findOne(subject);
        return subObj;
    }
.....
```

My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="    
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
....
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypacke.repository"  repository-impl-postfix="Impl" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

....

I found in this line subjectRepository.findOne(subject) ,subjectRepository is null,
My question is similar this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539417/spring-data-jpa-injection-fails-beancreationexception-could-not-autowire-fi)

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml document located under src/main/resources/META-INF ? Also, try getting rid of the repository-impl-postfix attribute of the jpa:respoitories element, might be causing spring-data to look for an implementation of your repo, rather than a spring-data managed interface.

Comment: Yes,I have a persistence.xml file in META-INF folder. And I already tried deleting repository-impl-postfix attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired annotation is activated by the statement:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="base.package"/>
```

If u do that, it would be initialized