# Is there a sample web project of integrating Spring-MVC and Spring-Data-JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I see a lots of examples of spring-data-jpa, but not a web project using spring-mvc, currently I try to use spring-data-jpa in my project, but failed, please see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544694/my-repository-cant-initialize-automatically-while-using-spring-data-jpa#comment13660373_10544694) here. And I didn't find a solution to resolve my issue. Can anyone provide me a skeleton project,so I can start over it. Or can you provide me some suggestion like is there a special thing to use spring-data-jpa, configuration? Version of spring?  The tutorial of spring data jpa sounds easy and handy, but not as same as my scenario. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/books) will help you.

Comment: That's not my case,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afternoon, wrote up a small example for this located at:

https://github.com/donkeystalk/d3

Hope this helps you out! Know I tried to help you on your previous question, and thought a full blown example was in order!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it out, and let you know my testing result

Comment: Great sample, I can get it running properly. PS:I changed version of hibernate-validator form 4.1.0 to 4.2.0, otherwise I got error:2012-05-18 11:55:45.611:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:Problem processing jar entry org/hibernate/validator/metadata/AnnotationIgnores.class
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: The issue resolved, I think it's the configuration, however,I can't tell what exactly where it is. Now a new issue raised up, please see my new post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647843/issue-of-pagination-in-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Can you at least accept this answer before i post on the next one?