# Issue of pagination in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying spring data JPA, when starting my project, I got the following error:

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'subjectRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:453)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:262)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:333)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:273)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:548)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
```

Here is my repository:

```
public interface SubjectRepository extends Repository<PSubject, String>{

    //public Page<PSubject> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
    public Page<PSubject> findByType(String type);
    //public Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress, Pageable pageable);
    public Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress);
    public Page<PSubject> findByUri(String uri);

}
```

As you can see I have comment the method of using pageble, and changed the parent interface from jparepository to repository.But I am still getting the above error message. Is there anything related to persistence.xml ?
My persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="volcano" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="4"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my spring data jpa configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="volcano" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> -->

    <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypackage.repository" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are reading the error message wrong:

```
Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter!
```

The methods you have commented out are correct, the remaining ones are wrong! If you want to return `Page<PSubject>` from a query method, this method must have `Pageable` argument. This is understandable: if you are asking about specific page of results, you must first define which page are you interested in.

```
Page<PSubject> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
Page<PSubject> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress, Pageable pageable);
Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress, Pageable pageable);
Page<PSubject> findByUri(String uri, Pageable pageable);
```

Or you if you are interested about all results use `List<PSubject>`:

```
Page<PSubject> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
List<PSubject> findByType(String type);
Page<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress, Pageable pageable);
List<PSubject> findByMacaddress(String macaddress);
List<PSubject> findByUri(String uri);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why you get that error if you use a PageRequest instead? It implements Pageable.

Comment: I assume it checks the method signature for the interface Pageable specifically. Even if you know you are going to pass in a PageRequest, you want the repository method to accept Pageable. Think of it like creating an ArrayList: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 13):

make sure that you are importing Pageable object from : org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

Answer (score 4):

In my case the import was wrong (from java.awt.print.Pageable).
Correct import class is : org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

Comment: This helped me a lot, because I was following a tutorial, but in the tutorial they didn't mentioned the correct package