# Spring boot creating beans error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stack-trace

I`v got error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionQueryController' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\controller\AuctionQueryController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.services.AuctionService]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.ArchiwumAllegro.main(ArchiwumAllegro.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstracException in thread "main" tBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchQueryMethod.<init>(ElasticsearchQueryMethod.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory$ElasticsearchQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.jaorg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionQueryController' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\controller\AuctionQueryController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.services.AuctionService]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.Auctiva:237)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:55)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 43 common frames omitted

onIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.ArchiwumAllegro.main(ArchiwumAllegro.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionService' defined in file [C:\Users\AP_520\Desktop\paa_allek_query-layer\target\classes\pl\bpo\archiwumallegro\services\AuctionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository]: : Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionIndexRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchQueryMethod.<init>(ElasticsearchQueryMethod.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory$ElasticsearchQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:55)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 43 more
```

**AuctionQueryController.java:**

[code](http://pastebin.com/GvGRHHUz)

**AuctionService.java:**

[code](http://pastebin.com/tEsg0FQ5)

**AuctionIndexRepository.java:**

[code](http://pastebin.com/cQHDFc0k)

Yesterday everything was fine, it must be a small mistake but I can not identify. If you need to see a files to write I will add it.

Problem resolve in AuctionIndexRepository I think i musted clicked to generate method or something like this in netbeans beacause that method is unnecessary.

So AuctionIndexRepository should look like:

```
package pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.model.index.auctions.AuctionIndex;

public interface AuctionIndexRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<AuctionIndex, Integer> {

}
```

Thanks for your interesting !

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647843/issue-of-pagination-in-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Could you add the Bean class in order to identify. Because it may error during regestring the bean

Comment: @Veeresh123 I added code to create a bean's what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The last nested exception in your stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage pl.bpo.archiwumallegro.repositories.AuctionIndexRepository.search(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder)
```

You have a query in one of your Spring Data classes that should return `FacetedPage` which, I assume, implement `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` interface. In this case Spring Data requires that your method has a parameter of type `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`.

You can find more information in [Spring Data Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be that error exists because of @Autowired in constructor for multiple properties.

So try @Autowired with any one of the below

1. Setter methods
2. Properties declaring.

**Setter methods**

```
 public class Class {     

   private MyClass myClass;

   @Autowired

   public void setMyClass ( MyClass myClass){

     this.spellChecker = myClass;
   }

   public MyClass getMyClass ( ) {

     return myClass;
   }

   public void yourrMehod() {

      myClass.methodCalling();

   }

}
```

**Properties declaring.**

```
    public class Class {     
       @Autowired
       private MyClass myClass;

       public void yourrMehod() {

          myClass.methodCalling();

        }

     }
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer could you give an example?

Comment: I think that this is not a problem because as I say this code to run yesterday, and the project is run must be a mistake somewhere in my code

Comment: Or chuck whether any Argument exception in AuctionIndexRepository.search because it is throwing IllegalArgumentException because of that bean creation failed may be

Comment: Whille calling search in stack trace is telling Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter may be you have missed any parmeter for pagination in NativeSearchQueryBuilder while pasing to search

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because you've taken the wrong Pageable import, 
check if your import is:
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

and not  Pageable from java.awt.print