# Paging query needs to have a pageable parameter [Spring Boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, paging, findall

I'm new to spring boot. I've tried to solve this bug for a whole afternoon but haven't get it right. I've checked these sites and tried to solve in their way but still failed.
 :[Issue of pagination in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647843/issue-of-pagination-in-spring-data-jpa) 
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/pagination.html
https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_42050545/article/details/84317816

My situation here is that I want to GET the data from my database on the browser. There are many data, and I want to separate the data by page. Every page only has 3 data. And when I pass the page number through browser, for example, *http:localhost:8080/test?page=1*, I'll need to see the according data containing in the very page.

here is my **Contoller**  :

```
//I have @autowired ExampleService here beforehand

@GetMapping("/test")
public Page<DatabaseTableName> getDataByPage(@RequestParam(value="page") int pageNum){
return exampleService.separatePage(pageNum);}
```

here is my **Repository**:

```
Page<DatabaseTableName> findAll(Pageable pageable);
List<DatabaseTableName> findAll(String id);
```

here is my **ServiceImplementation class**:

```
//I have @autowired ExampleRepository here beforehand

@Override
public Page<DatabaseTableName> separatePage(int pageNum){
return exampleRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNum, 3));
```

My error messages basically are :

```
Failed to load Application Context

error creating bean with name 'exampleRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.illegalargumentexception Paging query needs to have a pageable parameter! offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page.com.practice.repo.ExampleRepository.findAll(java.awt.print.pageable)
```

I get confused with Paging
     **query needs to have a pageable parameter** don't exactly know how to assign the parameter, I've tried to add `List<DatabaseTableName> findAll(String id)` to Repository, and I thought it should solve the problem but it did not. Pls provide some guide. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You have imported incorrectly `Pageable` from `java.awt.print` while it should be imported from `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`.  If you needed to add a parameter for a `findAll` method, you should have used method `findAllById(String id)`

Comment: @AlexRudenko thank you so much!  it works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your import statement:

```java
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
```